# How do I add the index after concatenate dataframes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I concatenate the files and try to rename the column. But it shows me the error. If I want to add index after concatenate, how should I fix the code?

```
total = [df01,df02,df03,df04,df05,df06,df07,df08,df09,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15]
date_count = pd.concat(total, axis=0)
date_count
```

**First output**

```
                        new_sentiment
date    new_sentiment   
2020-03-06  POSITIVE    1
2020-03-17  NEGATIVE    1
            NEUTRAL     1
2020-03-18  NEUTRAL     1
2020-03-23  NEUTRAL     1
... ... ...
2021-05-30  NEGATIVE    89
            POSITIVE    13
2021-05-31  NEGATIVE    13
            NEUTRAL     11
            POSITIVE    2
760 rows × 1 columns
```

```
date_count.columns(['date','new_sentiment','count'])
```

**Second output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-57eb7952ea0a> in <module>
----> 1 date_count.columns(['date','new_sentiment','count'])

TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This ?
date_count.columns=['date']
date_count.rename_axis(index=['date','new_sentiment'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make columns from the index, you should use:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This line will create column from each part of your multiindex